# How to order the Cronjobs to avoid overlap or conflict

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

I am running two cronjobs for python script every 5 minutes on ubuntu system, both are running successfully but not in the same order. when I checked log I found that some times second job ran first and some times befor completing first job second job triggered.Is there any way I can schedule in such a way that 2nd job should start after completing first job and both should run every 5 mins.

```html
*/5 * * * * cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3 comand.py -pgw y
*/5 * * * * cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3 comand.py -px y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though you're running the same script at the same time with two different entries in crontab, those are treated as two different cron tasks. Not sure what OS you're using. But the typical order for Ubuntu is top-down (in parallel), i.e. let's say you've three tasks defined in crontab like this:

```sh
* * * * * T1
* * * * * T2
* * * * * T3
```

T1 starts first, then T2 without waiting for T1 to complete, then T3 without waiting for T2 or T1 to complete. Ubuntu inherits this order from Debian. But in general this behavior may vary by Linux distributions or versions and cron implementation. And it really doesn't make sense to depend on it to be the same. For instance, in FreeBSD, the order is [bottom-up](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2003-July/011538.html). If the scripts depend on each other, best to call them in sequence, one from the other, or from a common wrapper script, which is the only one cron actually executes. The overlapping logs that you have seen might be due to the first change directory command before the actual invocation of your script in both tasks. You might want to try specifying the absolute path of your script.

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script/comand.py -pgw y
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script/comand.py -px y
```

Another option is to create a sample wrapper script something like this and schedule it in crontab. You're free to modify.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script/comand.py -pgw y > /path/to/task1.log 2>&1 &
TASK1_PID=$!
echo "Task1 PID: $TASK1_PID Started"
while ps -p $TASK1_PID; do sleep 1; done; echo "Task1 PID: $TASK1_PID Completed"

/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script/comand.py -pgw y > /path/to/task2.log 2>&1 &
TASK2_PID=$!
echo "Task2 PID: $TASK2_PID Started"
while ps -p $TASK2_PID; do sleep 1; done; echo "Task2 PID: $TASK2_PID: Completed"
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu. I want this in the order T2 should start after completion of T1 and T3 should start after completion of T2. Is there any way for this?

Comment: Then you can create a wrapper script and call the scripts in sequence one after the other "in the order you want" (For example T1, T2, T3). And put an entry in the crontab to run the wrapper script.

Comment: Thank you for the info.Could you please explain how to create wrapper script or add explination as answer?

Comment: Added a sample script, you wanna grab that?